# UbuntuOnAir: "Ask AskUbuntu"

Tags: discussion

On July 12, 2021, [popey](https://askubuntu.com/users/612/popey), Developer Advocate at Canonical, shared this link in [Ask Ubuntu General Room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58598338#58598338): https://twitter.com/ubuntu/status/1414611927993622532

Here's the tweet:

> It's a 'questioning' week for UbuntuOnAir when we invite AskUbuntu to come join us!  Rhys and Monica will be chatting with AskUbuntu moderators about everything they do to help your support questions get answered! ‍ Tune in at noon UTC on 15 July!
>
> https://youtu.be/y1Yvte7EZD0

Here are my questions:

- Why is there no announcement about this event in the Ask Ubuntu Meta?
- Can the moderators please post a post in Ask Ubuntu Meta explaining about the event including details like who approached whom (did Canonical approach Stack Exchange or did Ask Ubuntu moderators approach Canonical?) to talk about having this event and inviting Ask Ubuntu community members to participate in the live stream?
- Who are the moderators participating in the event?
- Our website name is Ask Ubuntu right? Or is it AskUbuntu according to Canonical?

---

**Edit**: Link to official announcement post: [Join us on UbuntuOnAir on 15th July 12:00 UTC!](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19663)

Comment: Ubuntu On-Air is managed independently from Ask Ubuntu typically.  They've "invited" Ask Ubuntu to join, but the individuals who have been invited (fyi: I have insight being on the Community Council) aren't going to be aware of the original "Ask Ubuntu" formation typically, unless there's new people I'm not aware of on the invite list...)  I think "AskUbuntu" is a typo, I'll let Monica know

Comment: @ThomasWard so it won't be you or any of the other AU mods? :'(

Comment: @terdon it'll be Zanna, but not me.  Timezone reasons (read below)

Answer (score 4):

> Why is there no announcement about this event in the Ask Ubuntu Meta?

Partly because I'm not sure how to explain what it is, since I haven't been involved in organising it - thankfully Monica and Rhys have done all that difficult stuff. I'm not even sure what they'll want to talk about! I myself only found out it was going ahead on Monday evening when I saw the tweet.

Also because yesterday when I was thinking of posting about it I procrastinated by writing an answer to your other meta question instead :D

> Can the moderators please post a post in Ask Ubuntu Meta explaining about the event including details like who approached whom (did Canonical approach Stack Exchange or did Ask Ubuntu moderators approach Canonical?) to talk about having this event and inviting Ask Ubuntu community members to participate in the live stream?

Monica kindly invited me to participate after Byte Commander mentioned it to me and I said I was interested. I didn't even know Ubuntu On Air existed until I started chatting with Monica about it on Discord over the last couple of weeks.

I would like to post something about it but I'm a bit clueless about what to write... since you have prompted me I'll get jokerdino to help me figure it out.

> Who are the moderators participating in the event?

I'll be there!

> Our website name is Ask Ubuntu right? Or is it AskUbuntu according to Canonical?

The twitter handle of Ask Ubuntu is @AskUbuntu - perhaps that was the thought behind that tweet.

Comment: I would like to sincerely apologise as it wasn't my intention to accuse anyone. I am so sorry. I was concerned that there was no announcement in meta considering the fact there was less than 24 hours for the event to commence. So I felt that there was a need for immediate action, so I chose meta. I am sorry once again.

Comment: @RandomPerson my bad, sorry for being grumpy, I just felt bad because I didn't already write the announcement D: I know you are only being helpful as always <3

Comment: It's OK Zanna. Please don't be sorry <3

Answer (score 3):

> Why is there no announcement about this event in the Ask Ubuntu Meta?

Only one moderator has actually said they'd be present - that's Zanna.  Nobody's posted yet, is all.  Moderators are busy people, after all. :)

> Can the moderators please post a post in Ask Ubuntu Meta explaining about the event including details like who approached whom to talk about having this event and inviting Ask Ubuntu community members to participate in the live stream?

The Canonical Community Team (specificaly, Monica on that team) approached the Ask Ubuntu moderators for whether we'd be interested in a session.  This had nothing to do with Stack Exchange.

I have no idea which bits Zanna is going to discuss about, so I can't provide a post explaining the event or details, sorry!

> Who are the moderators participating in the event?

That'd be Zanna, and only Zanna for right now.

> Our website name is Ask Ubuntu right? Or is it AskUbuntu according to Canonical?

As said in my comment, the site is "Ask Ubuntu".  I let Monica know.

Comment: If you don't mind, may I know why aren't you joining the event? Is it because of time zone issues?

Comment: 12:00PM UTC is 8AM UTC.  This is usually when I'm either mid-commute to work or still waking up, and in this case, on that day I have a 9AM UTC call so I will still be doing pre-work stuff that prohibits me from being present in the call.  If it were a few hours later I'd have been able to attend, but alas 12UTC puts it at 8AM (EDT) for me (or 7AM if US is not in Daylight Savings Time) which means it's a timezone issue that prevents me attending.

Comment: Did you mean EDT?

Comment: Time zone math is hard for most, isn't it?  EDT is UTC-4: 8AM.  EST is UTC-5: 7AM.

Comment: Do you recall the date when the Canonical Community Team approached you?

Comment: @RandomPerson nope, I don't remember the date.  It was fairly recently though, these things are being created at the speed of last-minute so i mean ;P

Answer (score 3):

(This answer will contain proxy-responses from Monica on the Community Team because she doesn't have enough rep here - she has direct contact with me on Discord though)

Per Monica of the Community Team (who prodded me with HER reply to this on Discord):

> Thanks Thomas! I just want to add that there was no announcement and no approach from Canonical because Rhys and I are running these office hours as individual Ubuntu members with other members. It wasn't a Canonical approach but a Monica approach and it wasn't an Ask Ubuntu announcement because we're speaking to Zanna from Ask Ubuntu. However, we do see our mistakes in the tweet that it looks like we're asking Ask Ubuntu as an org, and we'll correct that in our next tweets! That said, if any other mods or the whole team want to join for a community office hours session or your own separate Ask Ubuntu office hours we would LOVE to have you. At the moment this is all coordinated pretty low key on the Ubuntu Hideout Discord server but we'd love to have you, and seeing teward's comments we have sessions at 12 and 6pm UTC if you could make either of those.

---

More from Monica RE: RandomPerson's inquiry about where the convo happened:

> For the person asking if the conversation is happening on the Ubuntu Hideout Discord server, only some casual, low-key brainstorming conversations.

> Though I don't know what I can say beyond what we posted. We screwed up in our wording but we'd love to have Ask Ubuntu involved in future UbuntuOnAir programming.

> You can provide my Ubuntu member e-mail (madhens@ubuntu.com) if anyone would like to speak to me directly, but I think that's the best way for me to handle this particular situation going forwards.

So forward your questions to Monica directly - email above.

Comment: So the conversation is happening in [Ubuntu Hideout](https://ubuntuhideout.com/about) Discord server?