# Join us on UbuntuOnAir on 15th July 12:00 UTC!

Tags: discussion, ubuntu-community

Monica and Rhys from the Ubuntu Community Team have kindly [invited the mod team](https://twitter.com/ubuntu/status/1415328236146417670) to participate in a Community Office Hours session to chat about Ask Ubuntu.

You can catch it [here on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1Yvte7EZD0) on 15th July at noon UTC.

> It's a 'questioning' week's UbuntuOnAir when we chat with Zanna, an Ask Ubuntu moderator!  Rhys and Monica will be chatting with her about how she came to Ubuntu and the amazing work Ask Ubuntu moderators do to support this support resource!

Thanks to Random Person for [posting about it](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19657/ubuntuonair-ask-askubuntu) already and prompting me to let y'all know about it.

---

**Edit**: If you missed it, you can still watch the session at the YouTube link above :)

Comment: This link might be helpful: https://savvytime.com/converter

Comment: Great appearance @Zanna ! 

Comment: 80+ upvotes on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/okszrp/meet_an_ask_ubuntu_mod_during_ubuntuonair/ ... Cool!

Answer (score 5):

It was a great session Zanna! Good job!

I would love to see more of these events :)

---

The pose in the thumbnail of the video is XD

[image: Thumbnail of the video]

Comment: thanks a lot :D

Comment: @Zanna You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

A fabulous appearance. Best Office Hour yet.

I learned a lot about more ways that I should be helping folks and contributing -- like more editing titles, being gentler with homework problems, and looking for ways to help update/replace old answers.

I really like the feedback about the Moderators' vision and the gaps that they see.

Comment: Thank you so much :D

Answer (score -1):

Here's a [countdown](https://www.timeanddate.com/countdown/generic?iso=20210715T12&p0=1440&msg=UbuntuOnAir%3A%20Meet%20an%20Ask%20Ubuntu%20Moderator%21%20%7C%20Community%20Office%20Hours&font=sanserif&csz=1).

[image: Tick Tock GIF]