# We need to ensure that Ask Ubuntu's archive remains publically available

Tags: discussion

I was disappointed to find out that this is a problem:

- [June 2023 Data Dump is missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389922/june-2023-data-dump-is-missing/390023#390023)

We need to make sure we preserve our community contributions for the next generation, does anyone have the bandwidth to investigate this?

Comment: This profit driven plan of Stack Overflow, Inc. has inadvertently surfaced at the worst possible time. Unbelievable, I had thought that the company had *already* sunk to its lowest possible level in terms of its Community engagement...

Comment: @andrew.46-OnStrike We [may need a new host](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/20324/im-going-on-a-general-moderation-strike-due-to-the-new-ai-content-policy-forced#comment46089_20324), say I.

Comment: FYI: SE has resumed data dumps and a copy of the anonymized data is available.  Refer to https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390200/158829

Answer (score 3):

It would be great if the diamond moderators of our community can request Canonical to maintain copies of Ask Ubuntu's data dumps (Ask Ubuntu Meta's too).

In the worst case scenario in future, it could be useful.

Comment: An alternative would be nice but my understanding is that Ask Ubuntu and Canonical do not at the moment have that sort of relationship. Aspects of this relationship have been dealt with previously on Meta: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19689/57576

Comment: @andrew.46-OnStrike I guess we have some rapport with Canonical https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19663/. The sponsorship thing is not relevant here IMO. Or else, we can reach out to Linux Foundation, but we don't have a rapport witht them I guess.

Comment: Zanna did a great job there, Thomas Ward also featured in one of those from memory...

Comment: @andrew.46-OnStrike Yup, Zanna did a great job! Thomas Ward Ubuntu OnAir video: https://www.youtube.com/live/9ViKqRQnSwE?feature=share

Comment: I am still waiting for the call :)

Comment: Canonical wouldn't want to maintain copies of the data dumps probably.  I do have a copy of the data dumps myself from when they released earlier June, I'll probably start downloading copies of Ask Ubuntu data as long as we're on strike, but Canonical doesn't have a *direct* relationship with StackExchange (though Canonical holds the "Ubuntu" copyright so...)